# IMACROS search for specific user

Tags: loops, search, if-statement, extract, imacros

I have tried to make a macro to search for a specific user from links in the format of:

> http://website.com/user/ID-number

So my code is :

```
VERSION BUILD=8881205 RECORDER=FX
'No popup upon extractino
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
'Ignoring the error coming up because the username I'm searching for won't exist on all pages
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
'Set the user-id variable initiated at 0 and incremented by 1
set !VAR1 0
add !VAR1 {{!loop}}
'Increments the userID on the webpage
URL GOTO=http://website.com/user/{{!VAR1}}
'Check if the Username on the page is the same as the one i'm looking for :
SEARCH SOURCE=TXT:"Desired-username"
'Make a txt where there is supposed to be "desired-username"+userid
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
ADD !EXTRACT {{!EXTRACT}}
ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR1}}
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=test.csv
```

So with this code, the expected result would be a csv where the columns are all empty+UserID, (Keyword not found error) until he reaches the actual page where the desired username actually exists, and then inputs the Desired username near the UserID in the csv.

But it's not working, I tested it and I don't know what am I missing.
And if anyone has a better way of doing this (Which I'm pretty sure you do because my code is absolutely horrible), kindly share. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Comment your line `SET !ERRORIGNORE YES` and see what errors occur. (For example, the SEARCH command throws an error when the text isn’t found in the source code. I have no idea for what purpose it stands there.)

Comment: @Shugar In order to make a loop that searches for the desired username, I need to use the search fuction, if you search for something that is not already existing in the webpage, it will crash with an error saying "xxxx not found", so instead of stopping the script, I want it to increment the page, and then search the next one, and so on, until it actually finds the username..

Comment: With `SET !ERRORIGNORE YES` is there any difference in macro execution if it has found the searched text or if it hasn't found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment your line SET !ERRORIGNORE YES